# how to customize angular2-query-builder for getting static or dynamic value

Tags: customization, angular2-query-builder

on creating a rule by angular2-query-builder I want to allow users to select the static value or select that from a specific field.
how can do it?
I can add a new feather to angular2-query-builder?

[image]